# no GNOME Login Sound in startup applications?

Tags: gnome, login

There is no "GNOME Login Sound" option in Startup Application?

Answer (score 0):

You can add it in, just open Startup Applications, and click on add

[image]

for the Command enter: `/usr/bin/canberra-gtk-play --id="desktop-login" --description="GNOME Login"`

For the description you can enter anything you want, the default that comes with it is  as in the image below.

[image]

Once done you should see it as in the image below.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. Is it possible to change the default drum sound to user defined sound? I don't have enough reputations to vote your answer up. :(

Comment: Yes you can.  Its in `/usr/share/sounds/ubuntu/stereo/desktop-login.ogg`.  Replace that file with your file.  If this answered your question, you may mark this answer as accepted.